# How to play AVPlayerItems immediately

Tags: swift, swift3, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem

I'm using `AVPlayer` which I connect to an remote `URL` via an `AVPlayerItem`. The problem is that I want to play the sound from the `URL` immediately and don't let the user wait for the `AVPlayer` to buffer.

The thing is that if the remote `URL's` asset media is very short then it doesn't buffer for long at all but if the media is a bit longer it takes a while.

Is there a way to skip the buffering process or at least shorten it substantially?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664519/how-to-buffer-audio-using-avplayer-in-ios) might be useful to your case.

Comment: No the underlying problem is that AVPlayer(Item) uses it's property .status which returns AVPlayerItemStatus.readyToPlay when the item is ready to play. This property is a get only and is based on some algorithm made by Apple.

Comment: I "solved" it by adding a timer that played the audio with AVPlayer.playImmediately(atRate: 1) after 0.5 seconds. This makes it much more responsive

Comment: Though I would need it to be quicker than that so any help is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swift 5**

You just need to use the [automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1643482-automaticallywaitstominimizestal) property.

```
player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
player.playImmediately(atRate: 1.0)
```

Comment: Haven't tested but I'll mark this as answered as it seems like the correct way to do it.