# Slow video loading inside collection view cells

Tags: swift, video, video-streaming, collectionview

I have a collection view that plays short videos (3-5 sec) on each cell with full screen. The first cells take around 4 seconds to load, but the next ones load faster. The user experience is very poor because the app seems frozen at the beginning.

I tried different things but the result is the same so far. I tried to play the videos inside each cell instance and also from cellForItemAt an willDisplay. For the video player I am using a library called SwiftVideoBackground. I also tried to play videos with AVPlayer and also what this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628601/how-to-play-avplayeritems-immediately) says.

Each cell has a button to play another video, which also takes around 3 seconds to load.

I am streaming video files from Amazon AWS S3 using AWSCloudFront

```
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let cell = cell as? UserFeedCollectionViewCell {

            cell.videoBackground.play(view: cell.videoPlayer, url: cell.contentUrl, isMuted: false)
            cell.videoBackground.restart()

        }
```

And inside UserFeedCollectionViewCell:

```
@IBAction func playVideoBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    videoBackground.pause()
    videoBackground.play(view: videoPlayer, url: contentAUrl)
    videoBackground.restart()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play AVPlayerItems immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628601/how-to-play-avplayeritems-immediately)

Comment: no, that's the thread I mentioned but the result is the same